# How can I close a Trac ticket with Git

Tags: git, trac

I have the Bitnami Trac Version installed:
Trac 1.0.10
Webserver: Apache 2

It is hostet on a Virtual Machine. Git is also installed there.

My Repository is a "Server" Repository on another Server, so TortoiseGit can't do a push/fetch/pull there.
I created a local Repository on my Virtual Machine where I cloned my "Server" Repository.

I make a change in my source code and commit it to my local machine. Then I push it to the "Server" Repository and fetch the new information on the Virtual Machine Repository where Trac is installed.

On Trac I enabled the "tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.*" and added these lines in the "trac.ini" file:

```
commit_ticket_update_envelope = 
commit_ticket_update_commands.close = close closed closes fix fixed fixes
commit_ticket_update_commands.refs = <ALL>
commit_ticket_update_check_perms = true
commit_ticket_update_notify = true
```

I also created a "post-receive.sample" hook with the following entries:

```
REV=$(git rev-parse HEAD) 
trac-admin e:\bitnami trac stack projects\Prj changeset added "(Standard)" $REV
```

After I did these things i tried to commit a change with the comment like this: close #8. (Ticket 8 does exists and is not closed.)

Now to the problem: 
After i Commit, Push and Fetch the changes it doesn't closes the ticket. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

A file name `post-receive.sample` would not work as a hook: you need a file named `post-receive` (no extension), and it needs to be executable.
See "[TracGit Setting up post-receive hooks](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracGit#hooks) as an example.

Only then the post-receive hook would actually run.

Comment: I use the "trac-post-receive-hook-0.12-new-commits-from-all-branches.py" as example and changed it Variablefolders to:
TRAC_ENV = 'E:\Bitnami Trac Stack projects\Prj'
GIT_PATH = 'C:\BitNami\trac-1.0.10-2\git'
TRAC_ADMIN = 'C:\BitNami\trac-1.0.10-2\apps\trac\Scripts/trac-admin'
REPO_NAME = '(default)'

When I run it, the console runs and runs and runs, without a lifesign. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: @Evosoul Did you renamed that file as `post-receive`?

Comment: @Evosoul Please use Unix path: `/E/Bitnami Trac Stack projects/Prj`: that script will run with the Git bash shell (even on Windows). Make sure to use the latest one (Git 2.10: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

Comment: For the console testing no. For testing with Trac yes

Comment: @Evosoul console testing: run a git bash first, and launch it within that bash session.

Comment: I try to run the hook (nothing happens here in the Git Bash) and the .py file (opens the python.exe). Am I still doing something wrong? I am new to Trac and Console working so please be patient with me

Comment: @Evosoul try with a simpler script (still starting with `#!/usr/bin/env python`), but with a simple echo in python, just to see if that works, both in the shell, and as a post-receive hook.

Comment: If I run it inside the normal console than this works:
#! /usr/bin/python
print "Hello"

Inside the Git Bash it says that the permission is denied. But I run the shell with the admin account

Comment: @Evosoul Try `chmod 755 <your_script>` and run again to see if that works better.

Comment: With chmod 755 post-receive there is no Error but i don't see an output or something else.